# Why would Linux allow thread to set scheduling policy and priority?

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks

I used to think that thread scheduling policy and priority are determined by Linux kernel, and we can't change them through code when we write an application running on Linux until I see the system call like **sched_setscheduler**. I wonder why would Linux offer this kind of interface for applications, what if a developer want his application to have a better user experience so that he make threads running in his application have a higher scheduling priority as much as he can through interface like **sched_setscheduler** which will make other applications running on the same os starving.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about it the other way around: How would you **ever** set scheduling policies and priorities if the OS **didn't** provide you means to do it? Any tool for the user / administrator to do these things needs such an API.

Of course, you need *privileges* for many operations, like setting *realtime* scheduling policies and higher priorities. As always, `root` (uid 0) can do anything, but there's a much more fine-grained control through *capabilities* (a process that has `CAP_SYS_NICE` is allowed to do anything) and *resource limits* that allow access up to a given priority. For details, read [`sched(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html), the section "*Privileges and resource limits*".

If you attempt to change anything you don't have the privilege for, `sched_setscheduler()` will just return `-1` end set `errno` to `EPERM`.